# Setting UITextField's textContentType to creditCardNumber overrides keyboardType setting?

Tags: ios, swift

I am setting my text field's content type and keyboard type as follows:

```
numberTextField.textContentType = .creditCardNumber
numberTextField.keyboardType = .numberPad
```

However, the resulting keyboard is the default QWERTY keyboard. The number pad keyboard only shows up when I remove the `textContentType` setting.

This happens both when I set these attributes programmatically and in the interface builder.

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

The keyboard type for a `creditCardNumber` field changes if you set `returnKeyType`.

Answer (score 1):

Is that what you're talking about? If so, either the two or just the one, the numeric keypad always opens.

[image]

Comment: My mistake: It turns out we are using a subclass of UITextField called [SkyFloatingLabelTextField](https://github.com/Skyscanner/SkyFloatingLabelTextField), so the issue must be somewhere in this class.

Comment: Yes, the problem may be with that library. That library could have a numberpad. Check it.